# Hard coding conditional formatting with scripting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got a sheet that I periodically update from the mainframe, looking for new incidences of the first 3 columns.

Column A is a 7 digit number
Column B is Lastname, Firstname
Column C is Date

Using the interface's Conditional Formatting resource gets me part of the way "there."

[Current Conditional Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m25o.png)

What I'm trying for:
[ID is highlighted as is the DATE where it is different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSRww.png)

I paste the new mainframe data into Column M,N,O and if the number is present in Column A the Number in Column M is highlighted. If it is not highlighted I know to copy the M,N,O into A,B,C.

I'd like to script this into a function and -also- have the date in Column O highlighted if it is different than the date for the corresponding record in Column C.

Comment: Can you explain the highlighting of your date values?  O13 is highlighted because it is different for the same record in column A.  Is the highlighting of O15, where the date seems the same, just a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two conditional formating rules may work for you.
Using the same sheet layout as in your sample image, try these rules.

For range M11:M18, custom formula is:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(M11,$A$2:$A$7,0),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

For range O11:O18, custom formula is:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(MATCH(M11,$A$2:$A$7,0),NOT(IFERROR(MATCH(O11,$C$2:$C$7,0),FALSE))),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

The first searches for a match of the unique number, from column M, in column A.  If it finds it, it sets the function result to TRUE, to trigger the conditional formatting.

The second searches for both the unique number, AND, a NOT matching of the date values.  If both conditions are true, it sets the function result to TRUE to trigger the conditional formatting.

Let us know if this works for you, or if I've misunderstood something.

[image]

Comment: If the formulas work out to solve your issue, please check the answer as correct, to help others searching on this issue.

Comment: Finally got some time to put this into use. Appears to work great. Will have to research applying those strings in a script. Many Thanks for sharing your knowledge!